# MA run-time error '3075' Syntax Error

Tags: sql

i have this code and it shows me run-time error '3075' Syntax Error and i dont know how to fix it . help me please

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE PUNONJESIT set Id_punonjesit= '" & Me.id & "', Emer_punonjesi ='" & Me.emri & "', Mbiemer_punonjesi='" & Me.mbiemri & ", Mosha='" & Me.mosha & "', Profesioni='" & Me.profesioni & "', Rroga='" & Me.rroga & "', WHERE Id_punonjesit ='" & Me.id & "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the manual data (e.g. Me.id) is retrieve from text box properties or otherwise? If they are text boxes, then you should change them to this (e.g. Me.id.**value**) so the access can retrieve the value.

Here is my suggestion below:

(You)

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE PUNONJESIT set Id_punonjesit= '" & Me.id & "', Emer_punonjesi ='" & Me.emri & "', Mbiemer_punonjesi='" & Me.mbiemri & ", Mosha='" & Me.mosha & "', Profesioni='" & Me.profesioni & "', Rroga='" & Me.rroga & "', WHERE Id_punonjesit ='" & Me.id & "'"
```

(Me)

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE PUNONJESIT set Id_punonjesit=" & Me.id.value & ", Emer_punonjesi =" & Me.emri.value & ", Mbiemer_punonjesi=" & Me.mbiemri.value & ", Mosha=" & Me.mosha.value & ", Profesioni=" & Me.profesioni.value & ", Rroga=" & Me.rroga.value & ", WHERE Id_punonjesit =" & Me.id.value & ";"
```

You can try it and see what error does it generate. Do let me know if it helps? (: